# Application upgrade without Update Manager

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have an application which is based on CEF(Chromium Embedded Framework). It is an custom application. I want to upgrade that application time to time.On windows and mac we are using winsparkle for this job but on  ubuntu (and I believe on other distros) there is no way to use upgrade tool. I have searched on forums and here and realised that apt-get and update manager is place for ubuntu.

Is there a not centralised way to upgrade our application?

Comment: What is CEF, what application are you exactly talking about and how did you install that application?

Comment: @ByteCommander I have just edited the question. I  hope it is more clear. It s a custome application we code our own. It  uses chromium embedded framework library.